# Удалить в строке последний искомый символ

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как из следующей строки убрать последний символ `-`, используя регулярные выражения?

```
String s = "aaa i-ccccc BB-4564dn";
```

Результат должен выглядеть так: `aaa i-ccccc BB4564dn`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660034/replace-last-part-of-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
s = s.replaceAll("-([^-]*)$","$1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Заменяем пустой строкой только дефис, за которым нет дефиса:

```
s.replaceAll("(-)(?!.*-)", "");
// aaa i-ccccc BB4564dn
```

Comment: Ну или так: `s.replaceAll("(-)(?=[^-]*$)", "")`.

Comment: Наверное я не совсем правильно объяснил ситуацию, мне нужно убрать последний символ в любом случае т.е. если `aaa i-ccccc BB4564dn` результат должен быть `aaa iccccc BB4564dn`, если `aaa i-ccccc BB-4564-dn` тогда `aaa i-ccccc BB-4564dn`

Comment: @dev.android Всё так и есть, проверил на примерах оба метода.

Comment: Исправил пояснение - всё в единственном числе наверно понятнее.

Comment: Не пойму почему у меня не работает(

Comment: Можно потренироваться на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), там всё с пояснениями по каждой конструкции.

Comment: @dev.android если вы переписываете с ответа, у вас не может не работать.

Comment: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) - сдесь все отрабатывает как надо, но у меня не хочет работать прикреплю [скрин](https://yadi.sk/i/sHPfEzB5pYP_vQ)

Comment: есть подозрение, что между скобками `) (` пробел. Кстати @PetSerAl предложил ещё более простой способ: `s.replaceAll("(.*)-", "$1")` основанный на жадности  `.*`

Comment: @dev.android метод `replaceAll()`, как и любой другой метод строки (`String`), её не изменяет, а создаёт новую строку. Нужно присвоить этой или другой строке этот метод, как показано в моём ответе.

Comment: @Имя Фамилия, Спасибо большое что подсказали, действительно мне нужно было всего лишь присвоить к новой переменной `String t = s.replaceAll("(-)(?!.*-)", "");`

Comment: @dev.android ну хоть бы тогда галочку поставили :(.